# Visual Studio Source Control Get all

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

We have a folder for 3rd party DLLs.

It is not ideal but when I open the 'Source Control Explorer' in Visual Studio.

I go to Advanced and 'Get Specific Version'

I choose Latest for the dropdown and tick 'Overwrite writable files that are not checked out' and 'Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version'

There were 2 dlls missing from the folder, but TFS thinks that the solution has the files.

Is there a way to say 'Overwrite all with what is in source control'?

Comment: Are these 2 dlls been deleted from local folder? And what happen if you right click on the 2 dlls and select get the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, "Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version" option will do the things like what you said "Overwrite all with what is in source control". See the link "[Get the Source for Your Team Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181385.aspx)" from MSDN for details:

> 7.(Optional) Select the Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version option.
>
> If selected, files from the server overwrite all files.

And also check this blog for your question: [Why "Get Latest" sometimes doesn't...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonba/archive/2008/08/28/why-get-latest-sometimes-doesn-t.aspx)

Comment: thanks it turned out I had a setup a 2nd workspace mapped to another folder on the drive.  I was actually overwriting the dlls but was looking in the wrong folder...doh